# PHP/mysql Syntax Error uncaught token?

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP doesn't seem to be working here I have made a single query no joins etc which seems to be fine when I specify the columns I want to display etc.

However when I have made a query with join when I try and specify the columns for the data sets I keep recieveing a systex error in the browser console.

I can't see what the issue might be...

```
 <?php
     $month = $_POST['month'];
     $year= $_POST['year'];
     ?>
    <?php $query = mysql_query("Select donation_tracker.donation_Amount, donation_tracker.Location_ID, donation_tracker.Month, donation_tracker.Year,donation_tracker.City_ID,city_markers.City_Name, location_markers.Location_Name from donation_tracker inner join location_markers on donation_tracker.Location_ID = location_markers.Location_ID inner join city_markers on donation_tracker.City_ID = city_markers.City_ID where donation_tracker.Month= '$month' and donation_tracker.Year = '$year'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $data[0] = $row['donation_tracker.donation_Amount'];
    $data[1] = $row['location_markers.Location_Name'];
    echo "['".$data[0]."', ".$data[1]."],";
    }
    ?>
```

Form Code-

```
        <form action="Data_Chart.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" size="4" id='year' name="year" value="2013"> 
   <select id='month' name='month' value='January'>
   <option  value='January'>January</option>
   <option  value='February'>February</option>       
   <option  value='March'>March</option> 
   <option  value='April'>April</option>
   <option  value='May'>May</option>
   <option  value='June'>June</option>
   <option  value='July'>July</option>
   <option  value='August'>August</option>
   <option  value='September'>September</option>
   <option  value='October'>October</option>
   <option  value='November'>November</option>
   <option  value='December'>December</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
   </form>
```

Syntax Error- Line 37 (Hightlights- br/>)

[image]
Thank you.

Complete Code for Charts_Data.php

```
<?php
include_once('conn.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Data Pie Chart - OSBlogger</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Areas and Totals'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Web Development Languages Usage',
            data: [

    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['month'])) {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
} else {
    $month = 'January'; // put in your default value
}
if(isset($_POST['year'])) {
    $year = $_POST['year'];
} else {
    $year = '2013'; // put in your default value
}
    $query = mysql_query("Select donation_tracker.donation_Amount, donation_tracker.Location_ID, donation_tracker.Month, donation_tracker.Year,donation_tracker.City_ID,city_markers.City_Name, location_markers.Location_Name from donation_tracker inner join location_markers on donation_tracker.Location_ID = location_markers.Location_ID inner join city_markers on donation_tracker.City_ID = city_markers.City_ID where donation_tracker.Month= '$month' and donation_tracker.Year = '$year'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $data[0] = $row['donation_tracker.donation_Amount'];
    $data[1] = $row['location_markers.Location_Name'];
    echo "['".$data[0]."', ".$data[1]."],";
    }
    ?>
            ]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <p id="dts"><p>

        <form action="Data_Chart.php" method="post">
         <input type="text" size="4" id='year' name="year" value="2013"> 
   <select id='month' name='month' value='January'>
   <option  value='January'>January</option>
   <option  value='February'>February</option>       
   <option  value='March'>March</option> 
   <option  value='April'>April</option>
   <option  value='May'>May</option>
   <option  value='June'>June</option>
   <option  value='July'>July</option>
   <option  value='August'>August</option>
   <option  value='September'>September</option>
   <option  value='October'>October</option>
   <option  value='November'>November</option>
   <option  value='December'>December</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
   </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: syntax error in the browser console? wouldn't that be a javascript or css error?

Comment: If the php in your question is generating json, you're doing it wrong. You should instead create a php array, then use php's built-in method to convert the php array into json.

Comment: Can you show us the *exact* error you get?

Comment: Sorry, but my eyes are not good enough for this error message...

Comment: It highlights a break tag.

Comment: It highlights a `<br>` because the `<br>` is a syntax error in Javascript. The `<br>` is there because it's part of the error message that's being thrown by the PHP. The PHP error seems to say that you've not actually sent `month` and `year` as POST variables. You've not shown us the actual form code that would POST those variables.

Comment: Posted form code aplogies for the clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is:

```
Undefined index: month ... on line 41
Undefined index: year  ... on line 42
```

If line 41 is line 2 of your code above, you haven't posted the values for month and year.

Try something like

```
if(isset($_POST['month'])) {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
} else {
    $month = 'January'; // put in your default value
}
if(isset($_POST['year'])) {
    $year = $_POST['year'];
} else {
    $year = '2013'; // put in your default value
}
$query = mysql_query("Select donation_tracker.donation_Amount, donation_tracker.Location_ID, donation_tracker.Month, donation_tracker.Year,donation_tracker.City_ID,city_markers.City_Name, location_markers.Location_Name from donation_tracker inner join location_markers on donation_tracker.Location_ID = location_markers.Location_ID inner join city_markers on donation_tracker.City_ID = city_markers.City_ID where donation_tracker.Month= '$month' and donation_tracker.Year = '$year'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
$comma="";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data = array();
    $data[0] = $row['donation_Amount'];
    $data[1] = $row['Location_Name'];
    echo $comma."['".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."']";
    $comma=",";
}
```

Comment: Makes sense what you are saying although I thought my form code which I didn't add before you posted your comment was posting the variables though. :(

Comment: Thats not the old code that invokes the error. Is it now running?

Comment: Sorry I substituded my 2 variables which were $month=$_POST['month']; and $year=$_POST['year']; for your suggested code both didn't work for me.

Comment: Is it now running with the corrected code? Is donation_tracker.Month really a string column in your table?

Comment: Didn't work mean what? Do your receive another error message now?

Comment: It is running with corrected code but throwing up undefinded variables, Month is meant to be a string.

Comment: Let me guess: replace $data[0] = $row['donation_tracker.donation_Amount']; $data[1] = $row['location_markers.Location_Name']; with data[0] = $row['donation_Amount']; $data[1] = $row['Location_Name'];

Comment: Ah nice it's pulling though data now when I look at it through the console. The error thrown however is "SyntaxError: missing ] in index expression Data_Chart.php:39"